# Why is it not easy to find the help center on the mobile versions?

Tags: discussion, design, mobile-web, help-center

<sup>I found other posts that suggest making the help center easier to find but they're quite different. For example, [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304120/348196) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315374/348196) are discussing the full version. [This one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188918/348196) is quite old and was asking for optimizing the help center for the mobile version.</sup>

I rarely use the mobile version (I mostly use the mobile app when I'm on mobile) but today I opened the home page of a site on the network (which I hadn't used before) and immediately started looking for its help center; **I spent over a minute trying to find it**. Let's take SuperUser as an example for demonstration purposes<sup>*</sup>:

I looked for it on the top banner(s) but couldn't find it, opened the menu and looked there and still couldn't find it there:

[image: Top banner + menu]

Checked if there's another menu on the right and didn't find any. I then had to scroll down all the way to the bottom of the page to look for it there. I did find it there (which is not a good place if it's the only one) but to make matters worse, it's even covered by that notice regarding cookies and TOS so it can easily be missed:

[image: Bottom of the page]

I honestly felt frustrated!

So, my question/suggestion is **why not make it easier to find the help center on the mobile versions by adding it somewhere on the top (or at least in the menu)?** We want to encourage users to go through the help center before posting a question/answer, don't we?

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>I would've used Stack Overflow instead but the new home page is meh!</sub>

Comment: The full site view is the new mobile version. It’s responsive to small screen sizes. We haven’t converted all of the pages yet so the mobile skin is still around.

Comment: @Catija Hmm that makes sense. Is it going to replace the current "default view" any time soon?

Comment: I’m not sure!  I’d heard some discussion about making it the default but keeping the mobile version around as an option but that was a few months ago so it might have been discarded for now. I really prefer the full site version on my phone because it retains the site themes, while the mobile skin is the same everywhere

Comment: @Catija, it's browser related. I'm using FF Android and in mobile view it's OK: [logged out, logged in, at Super User or here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hEZo.jpg).

Comment: @Catija I hope the mobile view doesn't get discarded! On my phone, I generally use it on most of my sites, I only use the full site view when I need it for functions that the mobile view doesn't provide.